# Redshift: Join super arrays of different rows

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Given a table with this schema:

| id | name | values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | `[1,2,3]` |
| 1 | b | `[4,5,6]` |
| 1 | c | `[x,x,y]` |

Can I query it to receive this:

| id | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 | x |
| 1 | 2 | 5 | x |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | y |

And be then able to filter e.g.

```
WHERE c = 'x'
```

or

```
WHERE b >= 4 AND b < 6
```

One way I found is this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.v as a, t2.v as b FROM
(SELECT id, v, index 
FROM 
  table as t, 
  t.values AS v AT index 
WHERE t.name = 'a') as t1
JOIN
(SELECT id, v, index 
FROM 
  table as t, 
  t.values AS v AT index 
WHERE t.name = 'b') as t2
ON t1.index = t2.index
```

But this is cumbersome if I want to combine an arbitrary number of rows (and slow maybe?). Is there a better way?

Edit:
Found this way working with `PIVOT`. That seems also a viable solution, but are there others?

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT id, name, v, index 
FROM 
table as t, 
t.values AS v AT index 
WHERE id = 0 and name IN ('a', 'b', 'c')) AS t PIVOT (max(v) FOR name IN ('a', 'b', 'c'))
ORDER BY index
```

Comment: Can that array contain less than or more than `3` entries for a row? If so, what would this output look like in that case? Same question about distinct values in `name` column? Is it always the same count of distinct `name` or does it change each run?

Comment: The arrays can contain arbitrary number of values, but all arrays with the same id will have the same amount. The name column also contains distinct values per id.